# React-Bootstrap. switch slides by custom button

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

I have a Carousel which I want to slide right by clicking on a custom button.
This is a questionnaire, so I want to slide the carousel to the next slide when the person selects and answer (button press)

I have managed to slide it right, but it seems to lose the index or something, because it goes blank with no information on the next slide.

Could not find anything on how to do this.

```
render() {
    let count = 0;
    const { index, direction } = this.state;
return (
    <Carousel
        activeIndex={index}
        direction={direction}
        onSelect={(i,e)=>this.handleSelect(i,e)}
    >


        {this.props.questions.filter(question => question.type === "Text list").map((row, index) => <Carousel.Item  key={`slide-${index}`}  style={{"padding": "0 20px 0 20px", height: "600px", width: "1024px", textAlign: "center"}}>
                <h3>{row.question}</h3>
                <div style={{ paddingTop: "40px" }}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={3} />
                        <Col xs={6}>
                            <div>
                                <ButtonGroup vertical block className="qst-vertical-btns">
                                    {row.question_list_items.map((answer, idx) => <Button key={`button-${idx}`} onClick={(i,e)=>this.handleSelect(i,e)} activeIndex={index} direction={direction}>{answer.list_item}</Button>)}
                                </ButtonGroup>
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={3} />
                    </Row>
                </div>
            </Carousel.Item>
        )}
</Carousel>
```

**default one**

```
handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
    //carousel next
    // alert(`selected=${selectedIndex}, direction=${e.direction}`);
    this.setState({
        index: selectedIndex,
        direction: e.direction
    });
}
```

**SOLUTION**
On the button add custom function.

```
onClick={()=>this.handleSelectButton(index)}


handleSelectButton(index){
    let newIndex = index + 1;
    this.setState({
        index: newIndex,
        direction: 'next'
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `handleSelect` function and your `questions` array? I might have an idea what's happening, but need to test it

Answer (score 0):

On the button add custom function.

```
onClick={()=>this.handleSelectButton(index)}


handleSelectButton(index){
    let newIndex = index + 1;
    this.setState({
        index: newIndex,
        direction: 'next'
    });
}
```